# Not able to retrieve results from DynamoDB table using index

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Im using a lambda function (ptython) that's taking an event and is comparing it to a value under a dynamodb table.

[Dynamo DB screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfZ4P.png)
[Indexes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyL1P.png)

The lambda is correct but im not able to retrieve any value from the database but the value is there. It says:

{
"Reason": "No Records Found",
"Success": "False"
}

*** Update:

I made it possible to retrieve the "Success":"True" with this last part:

```
else:
        #item = response['Item']
        print("GetItem succeeded:")
        print(json.dumps(response))
        print(response['Items'])
        if "Items" in response:
            return{
                "Success":"True",
                "Extension":response["Items"][{extension}]
                }
```

It is printing this:

```
{
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
      30,
      "lambda_handler",
      "\"Extension\":response[\"Items\"][{extension}]"
    ]
  ],
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "errorMessage": "list indices must be integers, not set"
}
```

I just need this output:

```
 "Success":"True"
 "Extension:"7777"
```

Please help me achieve this and i will mark the answer as correct!

[Lambda screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEQU2.png)

[Lambda test event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvETf.png)

Comment: I see you have two places that could return this error.  Which is being called, the "else" block or the "except" block ?  Are any of your debug messages printing?  Also, it would be easier to debug if all the code was copy/pasted into your post instead of screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're accessing the response from DynamoDB incorrectly.

```
 "Extension":response["Items"][{extension}]
```

The output of `response['Items']` is a list, which you are incorrectly trying to access via `[{extension}]`.  Instead, you should be accessing it with an integer, e.g. `response['Items'][0]`.  Typically, you'd iterate through your results in a loop, since `query` can return multiple items.

What happens when you print the response from the query: `print(response['Items'])` ?